# I want to disable retrieving Group chat (MUC) history while joining a group - Android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, muc

I am always receiving group chat history while joining the room. To be more specific, whenever I join a group, I am receiving the last one message(only one message) which I have sent to that group. I have tried the following methods to disable this..

- As per the [**documentation suggests**](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory), I have passed the value 'maxchars='0'' with the history parameter of initial presence while joining the room.
- At the web admin page go to Group Chat section, then Group Chat Settings -> Group Chat Service Properties -> History Settings -> Don't show History

Eventhough I have tried all these possible ways,  am still receiving a history message while joining the room. please note that **the message which I am receiving at the time of joining, contains delay extension**. if it matters.

Comment: What implementation is the MUC service running?

Comment: We are using Openfire as XMPP server.Currently we haven't installed a MUC plugin with openfire. Will that be a problem?. But we can still add new service from, Group Chat -> Group Chat Settings -> Crete New Service. Also we are able to create new groups in that service.

Comment: This question seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496868/is-there-any-option-to-disable-group-chat-message-history-on-open-fire-server), though I don't think it's a duplicate.  It's weird that Openfire wouldn't respect the `maxchars` attribute...

Comment: I have implemented the methods which are given as solutions there. But still why its happening?. Is it a bug in my android client(SMACK) library.

Comment: @Saamzzz Have you got any solution / workaround for this problem? I'm facing this issue currently and the below solutions don't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

**Try this..**

```
    MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(mConnection, room_name);
    Log.d(TAG, "JOINING => " + room_name);

    DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
    history.setMaxStanzas(0);

     muc.join(mNickName, null, history,SmackConfiguration.getDefaultPacketReplyTimeout());
```

And **if get "group is asynchronous" this msg, then its just like notification that you join group.** just put if condition for this in groupchat listener.

Comment: But why it return the history while joining or rejoining the room/group? Can't we disable?

Comment: yes, we can disable history form both side server as well as device side, above code disable history from device side.

Comment: and we alway getting "group is asynchronous" notification when we join or rejoin group

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. Still, the old messages are delivered when a user rejoins. Please advice..